# Behaviour of text search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I implemented MongoDB Text Search in my NODEJS with MONGOOSE application and if I search for something then the results sometimes don't make sense for me.

Can somebody shed some light on the behaviour of text search?
What I am doing wrong?

ie.i have an name of "Franz" - i search for "Franz" - no result
i have an name of "You are a hero" - i search for "hero - finds it
The same for other fields - sometimes it finds the entry, sometimes not

```
CommentSchema.index({name:'text',shortDescription:'text',longDescription:'text',"topics.text":'text',geoAreaGeneral:'text',geoAreaSpecific:'text'});
```

**BTW:** The indexing of topics (defined by `topics: [{}]`) isn't working -how to get that working??

Here my code:

```
  var queryParamFind = {
    "addedDate" : {$lt:dateTimeISO}, 
    'deleted': {$ne:true}
  };

    if(order.includes("addedDate"))
    {queryParamOrder = {"addedDate" : -1}}
    if(order.includes("featured"))
    {queryParamOrder = {"featured" : -1}}
    if(order.includes("upvotes"))
    {queryParamOrder = {"upvotes" : -1}}
    else
    {queryParamOrder = {"addedDate" : -1}}

    if(searchPhrase != 'undefined'){
      if (searchPhrase.length==0)
      {}
      else
      {
      queryParamOrder= { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } };
      queryParamFind= { "$text": { "$search": searchPhrase  }, 'deleted': {$ne:true}};
      queryParamSelect = { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } };   
      }

    };

  Comment.find(queryParamFind)
        .select(queryParamSelect)
        .populate("addedBy")
        .sort(queryParamOrder)
        .limit(page * onePage)
        .exec(function(err, result){
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    res.json(result);
  });
```

in example:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("588dd5be93ca1b09003cf41a"),
    "number": NumberInt(1015),
    "addedBy": ObjectId("586e17f808612e10dcdcdc35"),
    "name": "This is a new comment",
    "shortDescription": "Please find me",
    "longDescription": "Please find me",
    "geoAreaGeneral": "Europe",
    "geoAreaSpecific": "Specific geo area",
    "creationDate": "2222-12-29T23:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T11:45:02.585+0000"),
    "addedDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T11:45:02.585+0000"),
    "topics": [{
        "text": "Tag1"
    }, {
        "text": "Tag2"
    }],
    "__v": NumberInt(0)
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("588dd5df93ca1b09003cf41b"),
    "number": NumberInt(1016),
    "addedBy": ObjectId("586e17f808612e10dcdcdc35"),
    "name": "Hello my name is",
    "shortDescription": "Hello my name is",
    "longDescription": "Hello my name is",
    "geoAreaGeneral": "North America",
    "creationDate": "2222-02-11T23:00:00.000Z",
    "upvotes": NumberInt(0),
    "clicksCount": NumberInt(0),
    "updatedCount": NumberInt(0),
    "updatedDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T11:45:35.343+0000"),
    "addedDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T11:45:35.343+0000"),
    "topics": [{
        "text": "Tag4"
    }, {
        "text": "Tag1000"
    }],
    "__v": NumberInt(0)
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("588dd62093ca1b09003cf41c"),
    "number": NumberInt(1017),
    "addedBy": ObjectId("586e17f808612e10dcdcdc35"),
    "name": "My name is Hello",
    "shortDescription": "Fiind me via my short description",
    "longDescription": "Fiind me via my long description",
    "geoAreaGeneral": "North America",
    "updatedDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T11:46:40.956+0000"),
    "addedDate": ISODate("2017-01-29T11:46:40.956+0000"),
    "topics": [{
        "text": "Tag3000"
    }],
    "__v": NumberInt(0)
}
```

When I search for "Hello" - i only see "Hello my name is" entry

When I serach for "comment" - nothing

When I search for "Please find" - finds "This is a new comment" entry

When I search for "Fiind" - finds "My name is hello"

When I search for "North" - nothing

Get Indexes:

```
> [
>         {
>                 "v" : 2,
>                 "key" : {
>                         "_id" : 1
>                 },
>                 "name" : "_id_",
>                 "ns" : "main.comments"
>         },
>         {
>                 "v" : 2,
>                 "unique" : true,
>                 "key" : {
>                         "number" : 1
>                 },
>                 "name" : "number_1",
>                 "ns" : "main.comments",
>                 "background" : true
>         },
>         {
>                 "v" : 2,
>                 "key" : {
>                         "_fts" : "text",
>                         "_ftsx" : 1
>                 },
>                 "name" : "shortDescription_text_longDescription_text_topics_text",
>                 "ns" : "main.comments",
>                 "background" : true,
>                 "weights" : {
>                         "longDescription" : 1,
>                         "shortDescription" : 1,
>                         "topics" : 1
>                 },
>                 "default_language" : "english",
>                 "language_override" : "language",
>                 "textIndexVersion" : 3
>         } ]
>
```

Comment: Can you add some sample documents and the input values to the post ?

Comment: please add it to question

Comment: cant add it to question - tells me too long - please see my answer below

Comment: I have added it to the question. You can remove your answer. I tired your search it works the way you expect. What is your mongo version ? Mine is 3.2

Comment: Hi! Thanks for adding it! Mine is 3.4!
So when you search for "North" it will actually find something or when you search for "Hello" you find 2 documents?

Comment: I tried both 3.2 and 3.4 version. Both returned 2 documents each for "North" and "Hello" search. Can you show me the output for `db.yourcollectionname.getIndexes()` ?

Comment: I added getIndexes() to my original post - thx

Comment: Did you had time to take a look at it?

Comment: I did but I couldn't find anything obvious that would cause this issue.

Comment: Thx - I will dig deeper into that - maybe because of the set language?

BTW maybe you have some clue about that: The indexing of topics (defined by topics: [{}]) isn't working -how to get that working??

Comment: What is your language and where are you setting it ?

Comment: >                 "default_language" : "english",
>                 "language_override" : "language"

It was just there